# In HTML, what is the name of this object?

Tags: html

I am trying to make a website and want to make similar object like below picture (make a box that is with separate pages and user can move to previous page and next page). However, I couldn't find info or even its name even after some hours of googling. Is there anyone knows this attribute's name?

[Google Trends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3smeV.png)

Comment: it's a pagination, google it for more information,

Comment: @MohaMed Thank you so much Mohamed. you saved my day

Comment: By the way, there is a [StackExchange site](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) devoted to UI elements and UX design choices.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo okay will use that site when it comes to html questions. thank you

Answer (score 0):

so something like a carousel?
its like this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
  
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  
  
  
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}
.slides > div {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.slides > div:target {
/*   transform: scale(0.8); */
}
.author-info {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  color: white;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.author-info a {
  color: white;
}
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider > a {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  position: relative;
}
.slider > a:active {
  top: 1px;
}
.slider > a:focus {
  background: #000;
}
@supports (scroll-snap-type) {
  .slider > a {
    display: none;
  }
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #74ABE2, #5563DE);
  font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  
  <a href="#slide-1">1</a>
  <a href="#slide-2">2</a>
  <a href="#slide-3">3</a>
  <a href="#slide-4">4</a>
  <a href="#slide-5">5</a>

  <div class="slides">
    <div id="slide-1">
      1
    </div>
    <div id="slide-2">
      2
    </div>
    <div id="slide-3">
      3
    </div>
    <div id="slide-4">
      4
    </div>
    <div id="slide-5">
      5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 기쁨으로 !  기쁨과 함께! 도움이 되셨다면 공감 눌러주세요^^

Answer (score 0):

This is called pagination. Learn more:

https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/pagination

> Pagination is the process of separating content into discrete pages...pagination also refers to the automated process of adding consecutive numbers to identify the sequential order of pages.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/pagination/

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_pagination.asp